# advice on cms + e-commerce

Tags: wordpress, drupal, e-commerce, ubercart, virtuemart

I'm building an estimate for a potential client. I'll do some more research if I get the project, but need some ideas for now. I'm trying to figure out a good solution that won't take several months to develop but will still provide good flexibility for future enhancements.

My options I believe are:

```
cms+e-commerce plugin (e.g. drupal+ubercart)
e-commerce platform that is extendable (e.g. magento)
framework+e-commerce platform (e.g. ci+magento)
cms+e-commerce (e.g. wordpress+magento)
```

The site will be similar to etsy where users can have items that they sell with their own portfolio page. The client wants to add many custom features as well. Also, the site will serve up a lot of images and audio.

I'm concerned that using strictly a e-commerce platform will give me a lot of obstacles to overcome rather than use just a cart+framework. I know Magento is written on Zend, but while I have used Magento, I'm not very familiar with Zend and it seems to take quite a while to learn.

I have never used ubercart,wp e-commerce, or virtuemart, so I'm not sure of the limitations. The products will not need to be configurable. But we will need to store financial information. I'm thinking braintree's vault or authorize.net cim.

I'd like to do the framework+ecommerce platform route. But the client would also like a lower price option, I'm leaning towards drupal+ubercart.

Just would like some opinions from personal experience.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the non-commerce part of the app is at least or more important than the e-commerce side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked with wordpress and some free open source commerce plug-ins. This was really a pain! I ended up programming my own low scale solution. Later I also worked with ubercart and drupal. The latter was one of my most motivating experiences with drupal. I found that drupal with ubercart can do everything what i and my customer wanted. I strongly recommend drupal...but i've never worked with magento...

Comment: Thanks that gives me some more confidence. I've worked with drupal a little, and I think I should be able to get it to do what I want.

Answer (score 2):

If you use drupal and ubercart in future please read the book http://www.usingdrupal.com/ Using drupal by reading its chapter of ubercart you can easily create e-commerce website after reading this book ubercart chapter within a day . There is a book which is completely wriiten on ubercart https://www.packtpub.com/drupal-e-commerce-ubercart-2x/book. These both books will be very helpful to you for ubercart.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I will take a look at the books.

Answer (score 2):

I've just created an e-commerce store with Wordpress and using the plugin [Jigoshop](http://jigoshop.com/) for the ecommerce.

We use Wordpress as our CMS for all our clients and we've also branded it via plugins so there's no mention of Wordpress, it just acts like OUR cms.

Jigoshop is very easy to incorporate, it can be used very easily straight out of the box but as our site was very bespoke we tailored a lot of it just by using CSS. Very easy to use and comes complete with everything you need.

I tried various other ecommerce plugins for WP but they were quite difficult to tailor.

All really straightforward providing you have a basic grasp of HTML, CSS and PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I think wordpress is enough because wordpress is now a biggest platform in wordpress with millions of plugins oops sorry not millions, billions of plugins you just have to find a plugin which  suits to you and your site content well for e commerce i recommend e-shop 5.0 its a great plugin.

Comment: I'd imagine wordpress is the biggest platform in wordpress. Not much competition there.